# Selecting Data form a table when attribute Id is 1105?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, custom, order-grid, customer-attribute

I am trying to display a customer reference on the sales order grid which i have created as a custom attribute on the sales order grid. I added this to _prepareColumns() to create the column

```
    $this->addColumn('accref', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Account Reference'),
        'index' => 'value', 
    ));
```

And then this in _prepareCollection to try and retrieve the data

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('customer_entity_varchar', 'main_table.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.value_id', array('value'));
```

The attribute is stored within customer_entity_varchar and the data I need is from the column "value" with an attribute ID of 1105 however it is returning everything in the value column

How can i change this code so it only selects the Value when the attribute ID is 1105??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code:

```
 $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('customer_entity_varchar'), 
        'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id AND customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 1105',
        array('customer_entity_varchar.value')
    );
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Let me know if this works for you.

Happy Coding...

Comment: I thought this was working perfectly however i have noticed that it doesnt show orders which do not have any data within that table. Fro example if a new custom orders and they do not have an account reference then there order wont appear

Comment: Made edits to my answer. Pls check. Thanks!

Comment: This shows the orders but they are selected (have the tick in the far left box) and also i cant view them (click through into the order)

Comment: I have gone ahead and added an attachment with the query (which I have just edited). I am not seeing any tick in the far left box (point me if I have missed anything). Upon clicking the order it very well takes me to the order (not sure if any customizations on your end are not making it work, maybe an extension which has overriden the SALES_ORDER_GRID already). Pls check.

Comment: I obviously did something wrong the first time as i have just re-entered it and it works! thank you